# MDX: Tuple contains more than one member of hierarchy

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, mondrian

I want to display levels of the same hierarchy in the same axis separate entities. For example  I want [Customer].[State] and [Customer].[County] to be displayed in separate columns.

I tried the following query:

```
select NON EMPTY 
{[Customer].[State].Members * [Customer].[County].Members}
ON ROWS
from [Search]
```

but get Mondrian Error: Tuple contains more than one member of hierarchy.

Is possible to do what I want to do, essentially flatten the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if the following will work in mondrian:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      (
        [Customer].[Gender].[Gender].MEMBERS
       ,[Customer].[Marital Status].[(All)]
      )
     ,(
        [Customer].[Gender].[(All)]
       ,[Customer].[Marital Status].[Marital Status].MEMBERS
      )
    } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Philip,

Comment: This results in the members being in the same column. I want separate columns.